# C# Do I need to read stdout on separate thread?

Tags: c#, redirect, process, stdout, stdin

In C#, I am trying to run a command line program that gets input from stdin and then it returns the output to  stdout .  I need to keep cmd.exe running (using /k) and in a for loop, send in text and then wait for the  output before sending the next text. This works if I don't redirect stdout but not after I redirect it. Initially I got data back from stdout (although much later)  and now that is no longer working other than the initial call to start the program. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) says "Alternately, you can avoid the deadlock condition by creating two threads and reading the output of each stream on a separate thread."
Would that fix my issue and if so, how would I do that?

The code is set up as follows:

```
StringBuilde  sb = new StringBuilder();
    Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingdirectory;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;    
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => AppendData(args.Data); //this appends the output to a stringbuilder
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => AppendError(args.Data);

    process.Start();  

        //sw is a streamwriter
        sw= process.StandardInput;

    //now call the command line code 
        sw.WriteLine(" some.exe some.arg ");

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        foreach(DataRow row in dtMydata.Rows)
    {   
        mytext=row["Text"].toString();

        sw.WriteLine(mytext);  
        sw.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine); //This redirects the text to the program,

    }
```

Comment: As I recall, if you want to redirect both STDIN and STDOUT you need to do so asynchronously. I think there is a .NET example at [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardError).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I added the process.BeginErrorReadLine() for an asychronous read on the error stream as well and I am still not getting the stdout stream once the program starts running. I have a sync call to get stdin, and asynch on stdout and stderr.  I think I need to explore how to run these in separate threads.  That is suggested on the link you provided as well as the link I refernenced above.

Comment: In looking closer, in the debug   "Cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous operation on process stream."   as soon as I execute the asynch call process.BeginOutputReadLine().  Need to investigate this further.

Comment: I'm about to give up on this... using my code as well as many of the example programs,  when I call the async method process.BeginOutputReadLine() right after start, I get an error "Cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous operation on process stream."